# Does Renaming Windows server affect the mysql instance running on that server

Tags: mysql

I am posting this question here as there was no direct answer anywhere over the web.
Our team is planning to rename windows server on which MySQL instance is running. will it be a problem when MySQL is restarted? If yes, then What changes do I need to make in MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL itself should be okay - but I'd test it just to be sure.

However, anything that connects to the server will need to change - this obviously includes all the clients connecting to the database, but may also affect any linked servers if you're running a cluster, the back-up routines and any monitoring/log management/shipping you're doing.

It's hard to test the connections in advance, so it's quite a high-risk thing to do.